# InfoPath using ListData.svc/somelist?$filter xxx return 500 Internal Server error

Tags: 2010, infopath, listdata.svc

In my Case,

In the InfoPath form  ,the user click a button to get the data collection from listdata.svc.

When I try connect `http://testingsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` . It works

When I try connect `http://testingsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/customList/`. It works

But when I try connect `http://testingsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/customList?$filter=Title eq 'double'`

It will return the `Internal 500 error`.

Any solution?

**CustomList background:** Around 120000 items

About the filter function , its work on my testing environment , but when I deploy to other site collection , it does not work.

Is it the server setting problem?

---

error log

> Name=Request (POST:http://
>   site:80/_layouts/Postback.FormServer.aspx)    ec6c0e85-7e66-4f26-a90c-e66037111cf5
>
> 05/02/2014 17:28:26.27    w3wp.exe (0x0B28)
>     0x1564  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data
>     xmnv    Medium      Site=/sites     ec6c0e85-7e66-4f26-a90c-e66037111cf5
>   05/02/2014 17:28:26.30    w3wp.exe (0x0B28)
>     0x1564  SharePoint Foundation           Web Controls
>     cm8z    Medium      Failed to get SPGroupName from GroupID. Error Message:
>   Group cannot be found.   Callstack:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGroupCollection.GetByID(Int32 id)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.set_SharePointGroupID(Int32
>   value).   ec6c0e85-7e66-4f26-a90c-e66037111cf5
>
> The following query failed: ZipCode REST Web Service (User:
>   abc\testing, Form Name: VendorForm, IP: , Connection Target: ,
>
> ```
> Request: http: //sites/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XsnLocation=http:// sites/Shared
> ```
>
> Documents/VendorForm.xsn&SaveLocation=http://
>   sites/fin-vendor/VendorForm&ClientInstalled=true&Source=http://
>   sites/fin-vendor/VendorForm/Forms/AllItems.aspx&DefaultItemOpen=1, 
>   Form ID:
>   urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:VendorForm:-myXSD-2013-07-16T02-32-08
>   Type: DataAdapterException,
>
> `Exception Message: The form cannot run the specified query.  The
>   remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.)
>   eba0d76e-afa9-491e-9a5c-a73c52970da6`

Comment: Have you checked ULS?